# return a syncrhonized value from a syncrhonized block

Tags: java, multithreading

if i have a map of objects and each `threads` can go inside each `buckets` concurrently,resulting a block like

```
syncrhonized(values.get(ObjectToLock)){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< new Random().nextInt(1000)+2; i++)
    sum+=i;
    return sum;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
 syncrhonized(values.get(ObjectToLock)){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< new Random().nextInt(1000)+2; i++)
        sum+=i;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         for( int j = 0; j < 10 ; j++)
            System.out.println(*);
        return sum;
    }
```

*in this piece of code, each thread can interfere between them resulting in a `sum` distorted?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `sum` is a local variable. Each thread will have its own copy.

Declaring it outside of the `synchronized` block doesn't make it any less of a local variable, it just makes its scope larger.

Comment: if sum is declared outside sync block?

Comment: ok, so any code i put inside the sync block, is copied for each threads which can access it?

Comment: @OiRc No, local variables are created on the stack. Each thread has its own stack. This has nothing to do with the code inside the block, it has to do with how local variables work.

Comment: @OiRc What are you trying to demonstrate with the update? `sum` is still a local variable.

Comment: updated now, sorry. if i have a nested loop, that has got two local variables, each threads can print the entire "matrix" not distorted?

Comment: @OiRc That depends what you mean by distorted. If all the `System.out.print` statements for one thread have to happen together, then, no, your code doesn't achieve that in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: by distorted i mean, that each thread have to print the entire matrix without interruption

Comment: @OiRc No, your code will not achieve that if you are locking on different objects across threads.

Comment: well, i appreciated  your previous clarification on local variables, but i don't understand why the syso will distorted if each thread has to do this passes: for i- > from 0 to 10 and same for j, can you explain me why, i' ll appreciate a lot.

Comment: @OiRc Each thread is presumable `synchronized` on a different object. So no thread has to wait on another to print its own part of the matrix. So each thread's matrix may be mixed with any other.

Comment: why the previous for ( for the sum) remains "atomic" for each threads?

Comment: @OiRc Because each thread has its own `sum`. They are not sharing anything. But `System.out.print` has a side effect that shares the same output device. One possibility is, instead of doing `print`, build up a `String` value (of the matrix) and return that. You can then print it atomically (`System.out.print` is internally `synchronized`).

Comment: aplogize me, but  i want to understand. I understood what you wrote, when you say `each thread has its own sum` , naturally it's a local variable, but they are sharing the same for of this variable or not?

Comment: @OiRc No, they are not sharing `sum`. Each thread has its own call stack. When execution reaches the point where `sum` is declared, that variable will be pushed on the stack and therefore made available to **that stack only**.